# How to Migrate from MariaDB to InfluxDB Datetime to Time

Tags: mysql, timestamp, mariadb, influxdb, grafana

I am trying for the last few days to export some data from MariaDB into InfluxDB formats.

I export my data from MariaDB using the following syntax:

```
    select CONCAT("insert cpu_load,host=" ,HostName ," value=", 
CPUUsedPercentage," ",UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CPUTime))
 from monitor.CPUStats;
```

**The Output is :**

```
insert cpu_load,host=host1 value=2.85 1696683600
```

**The CPUtime data type is datetime with this format:**

```
2/11/2017 3:56:18 PM


The output insert statement gets inserted in **InfluxDB** but the queries in **Grafana** or **Telegraf** are not retrieving nothing because of the time formats.
```

**The Query might be:**

```
    SELECT mean("value") AS "mean_value" FROM "monitor"."autogen"."cpu_load"
 WHERE time > now() - 1h AND "host"='prodvert03' GROUP BY time(10s) FILL(null)
```

**And the error msg is :**

```
Your query is syntactically correct but returned no results
```

So i do believe is in the time column format. The **UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CPUTime)** it does not do the trick.

Any ideas or help would appreciated.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(`value`) AS "mean_value"
    FROM `monitor`.`autogen`.`cpu_load`
    WHERE `time` > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
      AND `host` = 'prodvert03'
    GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`) / 10);
```

will come closer.  I don't know what `FILL(null)` means.

A lot of gratuitous syntax differences.

Comment: Thx - but is not the sql - is the time format ! that i am trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your influxdb insert statement

> insert cpu_load,host=host1 value=2.85 1696683600

uses timestamp in seconds since epoch, while influxdb by default works with nanoseconds time precision, afaik. So, I suspect your inserted data is not stored in influxdb with timestamps you are expecting.

You may need to use precision setting in influx CLI tool:

`precision <format>    specifies the format of the timestamp: rfc3339, h, m, s, ms, u or ns`

Check InfluxDB docs for details.